# BusinessObjects IDT - automatically value parameter or prompt based on user prompt

Tags: business-objects

Is it possible to have 2 parameters that auto seed with a value.  For example if a user selects two dates from two prompts, I would want the two other parameters/prompts to automatically have a value of the two previous dates minus 1 year:

```
User Prompt1: 01-01-2018
User Prompt2: 02-01-2018

Auto Prompt1: 01-01-2017
Auto Prompt2: 02-01-2018
```

Alternatively, is it possible to execute some SQL in the universe and have the where clause as a user prompt?  For example something like this

```
Select DateAdd(yy,-1,@start_date)
where @start_date = user_prompt
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ok, so the way I acheived this was as follows.

In the universe I created 2 sets of 2 LOVs.  The 1st two LOVs use some tsql to return a list of dates from jan-01 to dec-31 for the current year.

The 2nd set does the same thing but returns the dates for the previous year.

[image]

I then created 4 prompts which were associated with the LOVs.  The prompts are named current_startdate, current_enddate, previous_startdate and previous_endate.

[image]

I then created 2 business layer objects (prompts) based on the current_startdate and current_end date.

[image]

Finally I created two business layer objects which were simply the 1st two date prompts minues 1 year:

[image]